# How to Cancel the Input Text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to implement a function that accepts only specific key values in RichTextBox. Is there a way to invalidate the key value entered with the keyboard?

Since I am using a translator, I will attach the example below because the explanation may be insufficient. Can these functions be implemented?

Incorrect result:
"Test Word"

(Enter K)

"Test WoKrd"

Correct result:
"Test Word"

(Enter K)

"Test Word"

This Code is part of the code I'm making right now.

```
    private void ClientSendDsp_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyValue >= 65 & e.KeyValue <= 70 | e.KeyValue >= 96 & e.KeyValue <= 105)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyCode);
            return;
        }


        Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyCode);

        
    }
```

Comment: `e.Handled = true;` ...also, `KeyEventArgs ` in WPF doesn't define the `KeyValue` or `KeyCode` properties, this code is for WinForms.

Comment: ... in which case, for WinForms, it's `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`

Comment: I think I put the wrong tag. It was resolved by using e.SuppressKeyPress = true; Thank you!

Comment: `||` instead of `|`.